# How to prove that the circle will pass through the certain given points?

Tags: circles

[image]

It is given , that AB=AC=AG.
Now,if we draw a circle with centre A and AB as radius then,how should we prove that the circle will also pass through the points C and G?

Comment: Isn't the circle the set of **all** points at a given distance from its center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the definition of circle in your geometry book?

It is going to be something like, "A circle is the set of all points a given distance from the center."

C,G are the given distance from the circle.  They lie on circle A by definition.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the circle
with center$(a, b)$
and radius $r$ is
$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2
= r^2$.

If this equation
is satisfied by
points A and B,
then points
A and C also satisfy this
since the distances are the same;
similarly for A and G.